# how to use the IO-WARRIOR-Library "iowkit.dll" with python?

Tags: python

I am trying to work with the IO-Warrior library "iowkit.dll". I would like to access the methods of iowkit.dll with Python using ctypes. But it has worked until now not at all methods. Particularly, I have difficulty with the "IowKitWrite" and "IowKitRead" methods.

can someone help me or is there somewhere Python examples of IO-Warrior?

Thanx